# Teamviewer: Not ready

Tags: centos, vnc, teamviewer

I have a kind of virtual machine with CentOS 7 in my school, but I need to work from my home.

So I follow a tutorial to install Gnome and other to create a VNC server, all this to install TeamViewer.

Then, I install TeamViewer 11, but when I open it, it says the famous message:

```
Not ready, Please check your connection
```

I try to input proxy settings but it doesn't save the changes, so I have to edit the `global.conf` file.
I know that proxy is well in the system because I can navigate; I can even do ping to 178.77.120.1 and it works.

But the problem still remains. Then, searching in the web, I saw I could change the SELinux config to permissive. I do that in another virtual machine and that works, but it doesn't work in my machine. It has a Wine problem. I try to fix it using:

```
# setsebool -P mmap_low_allowed 1
```

but that doesn't work.

Another solution was add to `mdns4` to host in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, but it doesn't work.

So I decide to uninstall, using:

```
rpm -qa | grep teamviewer
rpm -e <output-from-rpm-qa>
```

But when I installed TeamViewer again, it loaded the proxy settings, so I think it doesn't remove completely.

Here's today log

```
Start:              2016/09/08 08:37:06.584 (UTC-5:00)
Version:            11.0.57095 
ID:                 0
Loglevel:           LogAll (0)
License:            0
Server:             master14.teamviewer.com
IC:                 0
CPU:                x86 Family 6 Model 45 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel
CPU extensions:     p8
OS:                 Lx CentOS 7 (Core) (32-bit)
IP:                 xx.xx.xxx.xxx
Proxy-Settings:     Type=0 IP= User=
AppPath:            C:\TeamViewer\TeamViewer.exe
UserAccount:        root

2016/09/08 08:37:06.588     8    29 GX2   AutoLogin::Login: enabled: 0
2016/09/08 08:37:06.803     8    29 GX2   CMain::LoadResourceDLLs(): No custom resource dll found
2016/09/08 08:37:06.805     8    29 GX2   Win32_GUI::FontReallyExists: 'Segoe UI' found 0 matches.
2016/09/08 08:37:06.805     8    29 GX2   Win32_GUI::FontReallyExists: 'Liberation Sans' found 4 matches.
2016/09/08 08:37:06.814     8    29 GX2   InterProcessBase::StartTcpCommunicationInternal(): setting m_NetworkConnector to new TCP connector
2016/09/08 08:37:06.814     8    29 GX2   Opening local TCP connection to 127.0.0.1:5942
2016/09/08 08:37:06.815     8    29 GX2   Local TCP connection established
2016/09/08 08:37:06.815     8    29 GX2   Process ID:  L 32511 /  W 8
2016/09/08 08:37:06.902     8    29 GX2   SettingsIPCReception receive a SYNCHRONISE Settings command : UserSettings
2016/09/08 08:37:06.904     8    29 GX2   Received Control_InitIPC_Response processtype=1
2016/09/08 08:37:06.904     8    29 GX2   Received Control_InitIPC_Response runningProcesses=3
2016/09/08 08:37:06.904     8    29 GX2   Control_InitIPC_Response: all processes 3 completely initialized
2016/09/08 08:37:06.940     8    29 GX2!! ProxySearch.GetProxiesFromPAC: WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(WPAD) failed for URL 'http://www.teamviewer.com/' with error 12166, Errorcode=12166
2016/09/08 08:37:06.944     8    29 GX2!! ProxySearch.GetProxiesFromPAC: WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(WPAD) failed for URL 'https://www.teamviewer.com:443/' with error 12166, Errorcode=12166
2016/09/08 08:37:06.944     8    29 GX2   ProxySearch: found WinHTTP proxy: http//10.20.4.15:3128
2016/09/08 08:37:06.946 32646 4091542336 QX2   SessionBusWatcher: suitable bus found with address "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-LumdutjnU5,guid=8c230a14389528c505b45eeb57d008e6"
2016/09/08 08:37:07.070     8     9 GX2!! GetSimpleDisplayCertNameFromFile: File 'C:\TeamViewer\tv_w32.dll' does not exist., Errorcode=2
2016/09/08 08:37:07.070     8     9 GX2!! VerifyTeamViewerSignature() : WinVerifyTrust failed, result=2, Errorcode=2
2016/09/08 08:37:07.070     8     9 GX2!! MachineHooks: Library not found, Errorcode=2
2016/09/08 08:37:07.074     8     9 GX2   MachineID m=0 - 1
2016/09/08 08:37:07.077     8     9 GX2   TVUpdate::Init() Version-URL: download.teamviewer.com/download/update/ Update-URL: download.teamviewer.com/download/update/
2016/09/08 08:37:07.077     8     9 GX2   TVUpdate::Init() Preview Channel Number : 1
2016/09/08 08:37:07.165     8     9 GX2!! TVW Wine: SetWindowManagerClassHint: No such window, Errorcode=120
2016/09/08 08:37:07.195     8     9 GX2!! TVW Wine: SetWindowManagerClassHint: No such window
2016/09/08 08:37:07.199     8     9 GX2!! TVW Wine: SetWindowManagerClassHint: No such window
2016/09/08 08:37:07.218     8     9 GX2   ManagerHolderStateMachine: Switching from None to NotReady
2016/09/08 08:37:07.219     8    21 GX2   ChatManager::ChatManager: created
2016/09/08 08:37:07.219     8    21 GX2   ChatManager::Factory: ChatManager created
2016/09/08 08:37:07.219     8    21 GX2   IncomingBetterChatCommandHandler::IncomingBetterChatCommandHandler: created
2016/09/08 08:37:07.219     8    21 GX2   IncomingChatCommandRegistration::Start: registering for ready state properties
2016/09/08 08:37:07.220     8     9 GX2!! DragDropRegistration: could not register window, HR=80040155
2016/09/08 08:37:07.222     8     9 GX2!! BuddyWindow.LoadWindowPosUnscaled: bad lexical cast
2016/09/08 08:37:07.227     8     9 GX2   AccountLoginGUI::CreateLoginKey(): [OnlineState] System is set to Visible.
2016/09/08 08:37:07.234     8     9 GX2!! TVW Wine: SetWindowManagerClassHint: No such window, Errorcode=120
2016/09/08 08:37:07.272     8     9 GX2   CMainWindow::ShouldShowDynamicPassword(): dynPw=1 allowIncoming=1 id=0 ka=0 lanAllowed=0 lanOnly=0 networkState=1 showDynPwd=0
2016/09/08 08:37:07.278     8     9 GX2!! ServerControl: RegisterPowerSettingNotification failed with error 0
2016/09/08 08:37:07.323 32645 139768218244864 gX2   PulseAudio: Connected to server 'unix:/run/user/0/pulse/native' (protocol version 30, library version 6.0.0
2016/09/08 08:37:07.324 32645 139768311990016 gX2   PulseAudio: Connection established
2016/09/08 08:37:07.456     8    33 GX2!! WineMixer: Unable to initialise mixer -1 -1
2016/09/08 08:37:07.456 32645 139768218244864 gX2   PulseAudio: Exit main loop (0), err=-2
2016/09/08 08:37:36.780     8     9 GX2   CMainWindow::InitCloseTV(): Prepare to close TeamViewer
2016/09/08 08:37:36.780     8     9 GX2!! ServerControl: UnregisterPowerSettingNotification failed with error 0
2016/09/08 08:37:36.781     8     9 GX2!! TVW Wine: SetWindowManagerClassHint: No such window
2016/09/08 08:37:36.785     8     9 GX2   Chat::Stop: Stopping chat
2016/09/08 08:37:36.785     8     9 GX2   Chat::Stop: Cancelling of Start
2016/09/08 08:37:36.786     8     9 GX2   ChatManager::UnregisterIncomingCommandRegistration: destroying incomingCommandRegistration
2016/09/08 08:37:36.786     8     9 GX2   IncomingChatCommandRegistration::Stop: disconnecting ready state properties
2016/09/08 08:37:36.787     8     9 GX2   ChatManager::Close
2016/09/08 08:37:36.787     8     9 GX2   ChatManager::UnregisterIncomingCommandRegistration: destroying incomingCommandRegistration
2016/09/08 08:37:36.787     8     9 GX2   ChatManager::ClearAccountChat: clearPersistently = 0
2016/09/08 08:37:36.788     8     9 GX2   ChatManager::ClearNonAccountChat
2016/09/08 08:37:36.789     8     9 GX2   ChatManager::~ChatManager: destroyed
2016/09/08 08:37:36.789     8     9 GX2   IncomingBetterChatCommandHandler::IncomingBetterChatCommandHandler: destroyed
2016/09/08 08:37:36.789     8     9 GX2!! MainWindow.OnDestroy: WTSUnRegisterSessionNotification failed with error 0
2016/09/08 08:37:36.792     8     9 GX2   CMainWindow::OnDestroy(): Closing TeamViewer
2016/09/08 08:37:36.907 32645 139768235030272 gX2   XClipboard: Shutting down event loop
2016/09/08 08:37:36.955 32645 139768525608768 gX2   TVGuiSlave.64: Terminated
2016/09/08 08:37:37.008     8     9 GX2!! ConfigurationHub::HandleRegistrationResponse(): registering for feature 1 failed with error 2
2016/09/08 08:37:37.008     8     9 GX2!! ConfigurationHub::HandleRegistrationResponse(): registering for feature 1 failed with error 2
2016/09/08 08:37:37.009  5552 4147260224 S   CInterProcessNetwork: Received DisconnectIPC from processID 32511 (ProcessType: 2 in Session 2) with reason 1
2016/09/08 08:37:37.009  5552 4147260224 S   Process 32511 in session 2 has terminated
2016/09/08 08:37:37.009  5552 4147260224 S   TerminalServer::ProcessTerminated_Finalize: process 32511 terminated
2016/09/08 08:37:37.009  5552 4147260224 S   SysSessionInfoManager: updating session information for session 2 from GUI
2016/09/08 08:37:37.009  5552 4094196544 S   XSession: 2 [SysSession 2 [type=1 tty=4294967295 pseudotty=1 info=1 id= user=root state=unknown active=0 reliable=0]]
2016/09/08 08:37:37.009  5552 4094196544 S   Updated sessions: [ 1     ]  [ 2    root ]  [ 9     ]  
2016/09/08 08:37:37.009  5552 4094196544 S   UpdateOnlineState m_ManualStop
2016/09/08 08:37:37.010     8    22 GX2   CTcpProcessConnector::HandleRead(): Socket gracefully closed (PID=5552)
2016/09/08 08:37:37.010     8    22 GX2   CTcpProcessConnector::CloseConnection(): PID=5552
2016/09/08 08:37:37.010     8    22 GX2!  InterProcessBase::EventFunctionInternal(): IPC-Connection Closed
2016/09/08 08:37:37.010     8    22 GX2   CTcpProcessConnector::CloseConnection(): PID=5552
2016/09/08 08:37:37.010     8    22 GX2   CTcpProcessConnector::CloseConnection(): Shutdown socket returned error 10058: Unknown error
2016/09/08 08:37:37.010  5552 4147260224 S   CTcpProcessConnector::HandleRead(): Socket gracefully closed (PID=32511)
2016/09/08 08:37:37.010  5552 4147260224 S   CTcpProcessConnector::CloseConnection(): PID=32511
2016/09/08 08:37:37.010  5552 4147260224 S   CInterProcessNetwork::NewInterProcessDataAvailable(): ConnectionClosed session=2 ptype=2
2016/09/08 08:37:37.010  5552 4147260224 S   UpdateOnlineState m_ManualStop
2016/09/08 08:37:37.010  5552 4147260224 S   CTcpProcessConnector::CloseConnection(): Shutdown socket returned error 107: Transport endpoint is not connected
2016/09/08 08:37:37.011     8    22 GX2!! CTcpProcessConnector::CloseConnection(): Shutdown socket returned error 10009: Unknown error, Errorcode=317
2016/09/08 08:37:37.012     8     9 GX2   interprocessbase::SecureNetwork destroyed
2016/09/08 08:37:37.013     8     9 GX2   TVW Terminating GUI slave
2016/09/08 08:37:37.013     8     9 GX2   Wine: Wine DLL freed
2016/09/08 08:37:37.015 32646 4113962752 QX2   TVGuiDelegate: Terminated
```

Answer (score 0):

In linux , you can use proxy chains to force all processes to use a proxy , just check:

proxychains - a tool that forces any TCP connection made by any given application
to follow through proxy like TOR or any other SOCKS4, SOCKS5 or HTTP(S) proxy. 
Supported auth-types: "user/pass" for SOCKS4/5, "basic" for HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Well, saw that i have a problem with the public key of teamviewer, there wasn't solution even downloading the missing public key.

The only thing that works, was download tar.xz and run teamviewer as a portable.

Answer (score -1):

In my case (ubuntu 16.04), I only have to restart the `teamviewerd` service and then, teamviewer GUI restart with "ready to connect" state.